# Does PushSharp parallelize calls to APNs by default?

Tags: c#, ios, pushsharp

To speed up the sending of bulks of Apple Push Notifications (APN), it's recommended to parallelize several calls to the APNs (APN server) - Up to a limit of 20 concurrent calls.

Does the C# cross-platform push library [PushSharp](https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp) do this by default for iOS notifications? If not, how can I configure it to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it does.
Search for CheckScale calls, you will see that when it takes too much time to send a notification, the PushService will open more PushChannels, and each one of them runs in a different WorkerTask

Look in the code for 15 or 20, as I remember, this are the constants that define the limit for maximum PushChannels that will work together.